# Disable opt-groups feature in React-Select V2

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I was populating v1 with a data structure like:

```
[{"label":"email","resource_type":"Email","options":[{"label":"Desc","value":1}]},{"label":"survey","options":[{"label":"HXH","value":3}]
```

And then populating another select with nested options. But now v2 auto populates the select with opt groups because of the nested **option** key of my json. How do I disable that?

Comment: It would be great if react-select allowed to pass the keyword for nested options, instead of hardcoding `"options"` string.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything in `react-select` to disable the grouping but you could `map` your options before passing them into `react-select` so that it only includes the relevant data.

```
const originalOptions = [
  { label: 'email', resource_type: 'Email', options: [{ label: 'Desc', value: 1 }] },
  { label: 'survey', options: [{ label: 'HXH', value: 3 }] },
];

<Select
  options={originalOptions.map(option => {
    return { label: option.label, value: option.value };
  })}
/>
```